# Processing WM_GESTURE in C#

Tags: c#, touchscreen, gestures

I need to process Gestures from a touch screen. I looked at
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd353242(v=vs.85).aspx
but the only example there was in C++, and I need it for C#. Does anyone know how to handle Gestures in C#?

I came so far as to get a 
private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
function, but I'm not sure how to ID WM_GESTURE and get the GESTUREINFO in C#. Does GESTUREINFO even exist in C#?

Edit: A suggestion was made to use InkCollection - that seems mighty cool, but also seems to be a Windows Forms thing - I use WPF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processing Touch and Gesture Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586942/processing-touch-and-gesture-events)

Comment: it doesn't, you have to bring the [DllImport] and struct declarations yourself.  This has been done of course, at least visit nuget.org and search for "gestures".  That *handled* argument looks suspiciously like WPF, it already supports touch.

Comment: @BugFinder - Looks great...but I use WPF. Don't suppose it'll work there?

Comment: @HansPassant - I tried to use Touch.FrameReported, but there's only actions Up, Down and Move. I'd hoped not to have to identify things like a Zoom myself.

Comment: Well as there are books on the subject it should work - try reading Pro WPF 4.5 in C#: Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 4.5 or Pro WPF in C# 2010: Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 4 .. i guess your google is broken